# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'unlink' of undefined at Grid.remove

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, gridfs

I'm trying to delete a file by its id using gridfs but I get this error when calling the delete API.

Controller :

```
let gfs;

connect.once("open", () => {
  gfs = Grid(connect.db, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection("uploads");
});

exports.deleteFile = (req, res) => {
  try {
    gfs.remove(
      { _id: req.params.id, root: "uploads" },
      (err, gridStore) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(404).send({ message: err });
        } else {
          return res.send({ message: "File deleted successfuly" });
        }
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send({
      message: error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: How do you initialize `gfs`?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I edited my question

Comment: did you come up with a solution?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen  // Inititialise GFS, gridFSBuckets
let gfs, gridfsBucket;
 
conn.once('open', () => {
    gridfsBucket = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(conn.db, {
        bucketName: 'uploads'
    });
    gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
    gfs.collection('uploads');
});

Comment: @HeikoTheißen see my comment below, made a full video on this, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
exports.deleteFileByFilename = async (req, res, next) => {
  const file = await gfs.files.findOne({ filename: req.params.filename });
  const gsfb = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(conn.db, { bucketName: 'uploads' });
  gsfb.delete(file._id, function (err, gridStore) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.status(200).end();
  });
};
```

Comment: can confirm that it woks for me, ty so much Meir, you are legend!

Answer (score 0):

```
// @route DELETE /files/:filename
// @desc  Delete file

app.delete('/files/:filename', async (req, res) => {
 
    const file = await gfs.files.findOne({ filename: req.params.filename });
    const gsfb = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(conn.db, { bucketName: 'uploads' });
    gsfb.delete(file._id, function (err, gridStore) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(404).send('no file found')
        }
        res.status(200).send('deleted successfully')
    });
});
```

On client side:

```
    const delImage = async (fileName) => {
    await axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/files/${fileName}`);
    console.log('fileDeleted');
    getData(); // reminder to REFETCH the data so that database with deleted file is refreshed
}
```

I also made a video on this - full file uploads, multiupload, display and delete using MERN stack and NPM Multer thing, in here: https://youtu.be/4WT5nvfXcbs

Docs for the video with full code: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MxvNNc9WdJT54TpanpFBT6o7WE_7hPAmDhdRNWE8A9k/edit?usp=sharing